# How to define that some arguments in a data frame might not be used?

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ref_ws = ref_ws,
                 turb_ws = turb_ws,
                 ref_wd = ref_wd,
                 fcf = turb_ws/ref_ws,
                 ref_fi = ref_fi,
                 shear = shear,
                 turbulence_intensity = turbulence_intensity,
                 inflow = inflow,
                 veer = veer)
```

that is part of a function where I define optional arguments (`shear, turbulence_intensity, inflow and veer` )

```
trial_plots <- function(ref_ws,turb_ws,ref_wd,shear,turbulence_intensity,inflow,veer)
```

the variables `ref_ws,turb_ws,ref_wd` are mandatory but the others are optional.

The optional ones will generate an individual plot for each one in case that we define the argument in the function.

For example, if `shear` is not used, I want to continue and see if it can generate the next plot regarding the `turbulence_intensity` and so on.

At the moment this is is the error:

```
Error in data.frame(ref_ws = ref_ws, turb_ws = turb_ws,ref_wd = ref_wd,  : 
  argument "veer" is missing, with no default
```

How can I define these arguments to be optional?

Comment: Please share some of the data with `dput(df)`

Comment: Set a default value in the function definition, e.g. `function(..., veer=NA)`.

Comment: it seems that I have a problem when creating the dataframe. I am using is.null() to check but it seems that the dataframe does not support vectors with different sizes (size of the vectors that are being used and zero for the ones that are not)

Comment: @jogo the return of this function is a list with all the plots that I can generate(depending on the parameters that we have). but defining veer=NA results in this output: ```Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale```. NA is a logical value and stops the function because I am generating plots with continuous scale. Should I do a condition to skip a part of the code if some parameter is NA?

Comment: @JoãoMachado Yes, you have to handle the value `NA` for `veer` in the function with a condition to evite undesired results.

Answer (score 2):

Hadley recommends to use `NULL` value as default argument and use `is.null` test in the function body:

> Sometimes you want to add a non-trivial default value, which might take several lines of code to compute. Instead of inserting that code in the function definition, you could use missing() to conditionally compute it if needed. However, this makes it hard to know which arguments are required and which are optional without carefully reading the documentation. Instead, I usually set the default value to NULL and use is.null() to check if the argument was supplied.

From [Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments)

I think it's a useful advice and personally use it a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But do you use if(is.null(argument)) and if it is you break?

Comment: Also, it seems that I have a problem when creating the dataframe. I am using is.null() to check but it seems that the dataframe does not support vectors with different sizes (size of the vectors that are being used and zero for the ones that are not)

Comment: `is.null` won't work for arguments like `data.frame`. For this type of objects, you might use logical conditions as `inherits(data, "data.frame")`